# Leap seconds and std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, c++20, leap-second

I took a look att cppreference.org (emphasis mine):

> The clock `std::chrono::utc_clock` is a Clock that represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It measures time since 00:00:00 UTC, Thursday, 1 January 1970, *including leap seconds*.

Comparing that to the definition of `system_clock`:

> `system_clock` measures Unix Time (i.e., time since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, *not counting leap seconds*).

Is it actually possible to have both in the same system? For example, if the system clock is synchronized via NTP, then the server decides what time it is, and that could use leap seconds or not, but the C++ library implementation cannot know anything about that. Or, does the standard require a database over when a leap second was introduced?

Comment: `Is it actually possible to have both in the same system?` wait, is it possible not to have both in the same system? And what about `tai_clock` `gps_clock` and `file_clock`? Why is `utc_clock` so special? `does the standard require a database over when a leap second was introduced?` well, [it kind of does](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/timezone/leapseconds)

Comment: `Or, does the standard require a database over when a leap second was introduced?` In a nutshell, yes, unless the platform has another source for leap second information.  The IANA time zone database includes a list of leap second insertions.

Comment: @KamilCuk That file only includes leap seconds to 2008 but there have been some since. Is that the current version of the file?

Comment: `Is that the current version of the file?` Yea and no. No this is not eh newest version of the file, that repository is an old version some guy used. Glibc sources are available from https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html . Still, the seconds in the glibc source code has only up to 2008. IANA https://www.iana.org/time-zones has the most currentl data, in the tar.gz there is the newest leapseconds, which should also be distributed to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds` on linuxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTP servers give you UTC (in a seconds-since-1900 format). The current time, is the current time. It doesn't really matter how many leap seconds there have been in order to get there.

Where things get complicated is when a leap second is added. NTP will announce this in the moment, and various operating systems do various things internally to record that, owing to their propensity to store time as "number of seconds since an epoch" — Linux and Windows don't include leap seconds in this, because it would make their timestamp rendering more complicated (how many leap seconds have there been?) and they can't be dealing with. Instead, they just slow or speed up the clock for a little while around the announced leap second, so rather than actually recording it they just adjust their own seconds-count so rendering that count as a timestamp will appear accurate later.

*(What I don't know is how an OS will redetermine its not-really-but-sort-of-seconds count from an NTP transaction without knowing how many leap seconds to deduct; edits welcomed.)*

`system_clock` gives you this seconds count, which (on mainstream platforms) just comes straight from the OS (e.g. `time()`).

`utc_clock` gives you a similar seconds count, but one that is "real". On such mainstream platforms this will necessarily have to be the `system_clock` with leap seconds added after-the-fact. This historical data comes from the system too, indeed [some kind of database](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/timezone/leapseconds) (though the exact source is up to the implementation).

In conclusion, the data sources for the two clocks are (slightly) different, so there is no question of whether they can co-exist on the same system. But, the `system_clock` *probably* comes directly from your operating system, in a way that the `utc_clock` *probably* doesn't.

#### Further reading

- NTP and leap seconds: https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/info/leap-second.htm#os
- The new `utc_clock` feature and its friends: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r4.html

Comment: The example implementation gets its list of leap second insertions from the IANA time zone database and uses that list when converting between `utc_time` and `sys_time`.  `utc_time` is most useful for including the leap second when computing the difference of `time_point`s across a leap second insertion.

Comment: @HowardHinnant  By my reading, that's where the linked glibc repo gets 'em from.

Comment: FWIW, that repo is out of date.  Here's a convenient list that is kept up to date: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: The current version of NTP is defined by [RFC 5905](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5905). Prose written about leap seconds by computer folks is not trustworthy; I prefer to look at numbers. On page 14 the RFC gives timestamps for 1 Jan 1972 (2,272,060,800) and 31 Dec 1999 (3,155,587,200). If NTP timestamps were included leap seconds the latter number would be 3,155,587,222.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this working draft about time](http://eel.is/c++draft/#time) for C++ 20, which seems to be due out in AD 2020. It has a [subpage about utc_clock](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc.overview) which includes this example:

```
clock_­cast<utc_­clock>(sys_­seconds{sys_­days{1970y/January/1}}).time_­since_­epoch() is 0s.
clock_­cast<utc_­clock>(sys_­seconds{sys_­days{2000y/January/1}}).time_­since_­epoch()
```

and states the last value "is 946'684'822s, which is 10'957 * 86'400s + 22s." Notice that 10,957 days are about 30 years, so the value of utc_clock evidently represents seconds since 1 January 1970 UTC, where each leap second increments the value of utc_clock.

Since this is expressed as a conversion, it seems reasonable to infer the conversion would call upon a table of leap seconds, and could be performed even if the operating system had no notion of the distinction between UTC and TAI, and no concept of a minute which contained 61 seconds.

I must admit I am more interested in time than C++ and have not written serious C++ code in nearly 20 years.

Comment: You infer correctly.  Note that there is also a `tai_clock`, and even a `gps_clock` as well, and the ability to `clock_cast` among them.

Comment: And you can find an example implementation of all of this here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date